# Как смержить две ветки в одну, когда они обе внесли изменения в один файл?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge, pull-request

У меня ветка master от ней были созданы две ветки feature-1 и feature-2.

Пусть в проекте один файл README.MD. После внесения изменений имеем следующее содержимое файла по веткам:

README.MD в ветке **master**

```
Test README.MD
```

README.MD в ветке **feature-1**

```
Test README.MD
feature-1
```

README.MD в ветке **feature-2**

```
Test README.MD
feature-2
```

Теперь задача получить изменения в файле README.MD в ветке **master** в таком виде:

```
Test README.MD
feature-1
feature-2
```

Когда я делаю pull request feature веток друг за другом, то на второй ветке получаю конфликт изменений. Я понимаю, что видимо такой конфликт неизбежен.

**Вопрос:**

Какая правильная стратегия действий в этом случае, если допустим мы находимся в состоянии, когда изменения внесены в ветки feature и ни один pull request еще не выполнялся?

Comment: Помержить одну, во второй решить конфликт.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вот у меня вопрос: Конфликт надо разрешать при pull request второй ветки или еще до pull request во вторую ветку получить изменения из нового master разрешить конфликт и потом делать pull request второй ветки?

Comment: Мне кажется, что если перейти на мастер стянуть все изменения, потом сделать новую ветку под PR в эту ветку черипикнуть все нужные изменения и слить в мастер. Так разве не выйдет?

Comment: Что значит «до pull request»? Я предполагал что он уже есть. Конечно если вы его ещё не делали, то можно сначала разрешить конфликты, а потом делать PR, но вообще это совершенно несвязанные вещи

Comment: В `git`'е, как и вообще в программировании, нет одного «правильного» решения. Мы можем предложить несколько более-менее подходящих. А какой из них должен использоваться решает владелец проекта/работодатель